# apt-get install phpmyadmin on debian doesn't install /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on my webserver, using this guide:

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server

I did that once, and it worked like a dream, but I hated the looks of phpmyadmin (maybe the oldest layout ever) and decided to delete it, and didn't know that deleting is done with `apt-get remove phpmyadmin` and did in phpmyadmin directory `rm *` and thought that it's done. However, as I can't find the debian build of phpmyadmin anywhere, I want to install it again, but when I add `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, and restart apache, it give's me this error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 73 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

No matter how I try, I always get this error, and phpmyadmin isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, just be defining "include /etc/..." in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf does not make the file magically appear in said destination.

But now, let's fix things.

You can reinstall phpmyadmin by executing "aptitude reinstall phpmyadmin" in the shell.

Debian's version of phpmyadmin can be downloaded from here: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/phpmyadmin/download

You can search for Debian packages in here: http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Comment: did that, restarting but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Please execute this in the shell and paste the resulting line: `sed -n "73 p" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: And also the result of this: `ls /etc/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: first one says that not found.

Comment: and ls config-db.php

Comment: You don't have sed installed or /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is not found? Always paste the full output. As for phpmyadmin, please use the following commands and paste the full output: `aptitude purge phpmyadmin` and `aptitude install phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Did that, and I think it removed phpmyadmin and then reinstalled it, how I can access it now? **EDIT** Restarted my server, and it works like magic. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing configuration files is considered to be a configuration change, and Debian packages are required to preserve configuration changes. So reinstalling a removed package will not cause removed configuration files to be restored. You need to `purge` the package rather than just `remove`. This will tell the packaging system that you no longer want even the configuration files for the package. Once that is done you can install the package again and the configuration files will be reinstalled as well.

Comment: so what do I enter to command line?

Comment: `apt-get purge phpmyadmin; apt-get install phpmyadmin `

Comment: nope, still produces the same error.